# RxJava - .andThen() never called after .flatMapCompletable()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a `Observable` with a chained `Completeable` with a chained `Single` that is called at an interval of 5 seconds.

```
public void getCoinPrices() {
        disposable = Observable
                .interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMapCompletable(n -> {
                    Timber.d("Called flatmap completeable: " + n);
                    boolean isFirstTime = sharedPrefManager.isFirstTimeOpeningApp();
                    if (isFirstTime) {
                        Timber.d("Is first time.");
                        return insertFavoritesUseCase.insertStartingCoins()
                                .andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                                    sharedPrefManager.setFirstTimeOpeningApp(false);
                                }));
                    } else {
                        Timber.d("Not first time.");
                        return Completable.complete();
                    }
                })
                .andThen(getFavoritesUseCase.getFavoriteCoins())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(listFavorites -> {
                    Timber.d("List favorites called...");
                    
                    return getCoinsUseCase.getCoinPrices(listFavorites);
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(listCoinsWithPrice -> {
                    Timber.d("Called.......");
                   
                }, err -> {
                    Timber.e("Failed to get price of coins: " + err);
                });
    }
```

I can't figure out why the `.andThen(getFavoritesUseCase.getFavoriteCoins())` is never fired.

```
public Single<List<CoinStatus>> getFavoriteCoins() {
        Timber.d("Get Favorite Coins Fired");
        return localRepository.getFavoriteCoins();
}
```

I have tested the flag `isFirstTime` with true and false, but the `.andThen()` is still never fired.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: `andThen` only works if the source completes. You have an infinite interval that never completes.

Comment: @akarnokd What would be the best way to chain it in an interval?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the interval in the first place? Do you really want to repeatedly do the first-time check within the same flow over and over? If you need periodic sync with a single flow, don't return completed, but signal some value and keep `flatMap`ping subflows.

Comment: I'm trying to call an API with the interval. The first time check is to add the default list of items to call with using the API and yes I do want to keep the check. I spent an entire day getting it to work https://pastebin.com/Tcw3wfmy and it does, but I'm now trying to figure out if the way I did it is good or not or there could be an improved way of doing it. Any thoughts on the new code?

Comment: Also could you explain ```don't return completed, but signal some value and keep flatMapping subflows.```. Sorry I don't quite understand. So by ```don't return completed``` do you mean I should use a ```Maybe```,```Single```, or ```Observable``` instead of ```Completeable```? Also when you say ```keep flatMap ping subflows``` does this mean allow all the code to continue running after the first flatMap?

Comment: It means what you did on that pastebin file, keep chaining `flatMap`s. Do not use `Completable` because flatMaps require a value `Completable`s never provide.

Answer (score 0):

I got it the `interval` to work by using akarnokd's advice removing the `Completeable`. I used a `Single` instead and continued the chain flow by passing a value with `Single.just()`. Please let me know if  there's a better way or cleaner way to do it!

```
disposable = Observable.interval(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMapSingle(n -> {
                    boolean isFirstTime = sharedPrefManager.isFirstTimeOpeningApp();
                    if (isFirstTime) {
                        return insertFavoritesUseCase.insertStartingCoins().doOnSuccess(insertResult -> {
                            sharedPrefManager.setFirstTimeOpeningApp(false);
                        });
                    } else {
                        return Single.just("Did not insert coins, continuing stream");
                    }
                })
                .flatMapSingle(insertResult -> getFavoritesUseCase.getFavoriteCoins())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMapSingle(listFavorites -> {
                    
                    //update ui

                    return getCoinsUseCase.getCoinPrices(listFavorites);
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(listCoinsWithPrice -> {

                    //update ui

                }, err -> {
                    Timber.e("Failed to get price of coins: " + err);
                });
```